# Write data in NFC chip on Android Phone

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to write data on my NFC chip in my android phone? Please say yes.
It's saying that my the nfc chip is not formattable.

Answer (score 0):

Mates, it is possible. Android Beam is the way